# JUnit Assert with BigDecimal

Tags: java, junit, assert, bigdecimal

I want to use assert between 2 two decimal, I use this:

```
BigDecimal bd1 = new BigDecimal (1000);
BigDecimal bd2 = new BigDecimal (1000);
org.junit.Assert.assertSame (bd1,bd2);
```

but the JUnit log shows:

```
expected <1000> was not: <1000>
```

Comment: They are not the same object as expected.  You might be looking to check whether they are `equals`  Note: BigDecimal doesn't consider `1000.0` and `1000.00` as equal as the number of decimal places are different.  IMHO `double` is simpler and no more error prone. ;)

Comment: @PeterLawrey I wonder when will that be fixed, I really can't how is this useful in any scenario.

Comment: @MarounMaroun For backward compatibility, it will never be fixed.

Comment: @kAnGeL can you please revisit the ansers and  chose the most correct and appropriate ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`assertSame`](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html#assertSame%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object%29) tests that the two objects are the same objects, i.e. that they are `==`:

> Asserts that two objects refer to the same object. If they are not the same, an `AssertionError` without a message is thrown.

In your case, since `bd1` and `bd2` are both new `BigDecimal`, the objects aren't the same, hence the exception.

What you want is to use [`assertEquals`](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html#assertEquals%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object%29), that tests if two objects are equal, i.e. `.equals`:

> Asserts that two objects are equal. If they are not, an `AssertionError` without a message is thrown. If expected and actual are `null`, they are considered equal.

```
BigDecimal bd1 = new BigDecimal (1000);
BigDecimal bd2 = new BigDecimal (1000);
org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(bd1,bd2);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! You find my perfect solution :D

Comment: that will work only for BigDecimals with the perfectly the same scale

Comment: @PavloZvarych Yes, which is the case here. It depends if the scale is a parameter you want to test as well.

Answer (score 139):

The [official junit solution](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/issues/95) to assert that two BigDecimal are matematically equal is to use hamcrest.

With [java-hamcrest 2.0.0.0](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hamcrest/java-hamcrest/2.0.0.0) we can use this syntax:

```
    // import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
    // import org.hamcrest.Matchers;

    BigDecimal a = new BigDecimal("100")
    BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal("100.00")
    assertThat(a,  Matchers.comparesEqualTo(b));
```

[Hamcrest   1.3         Quick   Reference](http://www.marcphilipp.de/downloads/posts/2013-01-02-hamcrest-quick-reference/Hamcrest-1.3.pdf)

Comment: This also gives meaningful error message compared to accepted and highest-voted answer: "java.lang.AssertionError: Expected: a value equal to <0.22>  but: <0.222> was greater than <0.22>"

Comment: No idea why this doesn't work for me. Some kind of casting / generics weirdness. `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hamcrest.Matcher.describeMismatch(Ljava/lang/Object;Lorg/hamcrest/Description;)V`

Answer (score 49):

`assertSame`checks if both objects are the same instance. `assertEquals`checks if the numbers are equal in value and scale, that means i.e. 1000 is not equal to 1000.00. If you want to compare only the numeric value, you should use `compareTo()` method from `BigDecimal`.

For example:

```
BigDecimal bd1 = new BigDecimal (1000.00);
BigDecimal bd2 = new BigDecimal (1000);
org.junit.Assert.assertTrue(bd1.compareTo(bd2) == 0);
```

Comment: `comparesEqualTo()` is preferable to this because in failures, `assertThat(x.compareTo(y), is(y)` gives something like `Expected: is <0> but: was <1>`. `assertThat(x, comparesEqualTo(y)` gives `Expected: a value equal to <27700>
     but: <6700.000> was less than <27700>`

Comment: @slim Yes, the answer with Hamcrest gives a more meaningful error message. My answer on the other hand is not dependent from Hamcrest and explains the logic of why the accepted answer can fail.

Answer (score 18):

The answer to the question was already given. But some of the answers answer another question, namely 'how to compare 2 BigDecimals?'. The given solutions so far are either wrong or obsolete. I would like to suggest to try this:

```
// import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

BigDecimal a = new BigDecimal("100")
BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal("100.00")
assertThat(a).isEqualByComparingTo(b);
```

Comment: @roma2341 Could you please explain what exactly is not working? Perhaps provide a code example?

Comment: Method isEqualByComparingTo() use BigDecimal.compareTo() which is recommended to use. It is close to assertTrue(bd1.compareTo(bd2) == 0) but in assertThat(a).isEqualByComparingTo(b) you see expected value not just place of fault.

Comment: This is the correct answer, thank you. In 2021 we shouldn't be using compareTo==0 directly, like cavemen.

Answer (score 17):

Comparing `BigDecimal` with `compareTo()` works (as in: it ignore the scale and compare the actual number) but when unit testing it's useful to know what's the actual number, specially when the test fail.

An option I've used in this case is `stripTrailingZeros()` on both `BigDecimal`:

```
assertEquals(new BigDecimal("150").stripTrailingZeros(),
                    otherBigDecimal.stripTrailingZeros());
```

What this function does is remove zeroes without changing the number, so `"150"` is converted in `"1.5E+2"`: this way it doesn't matter if you have `150`, `150.00` or other form in `otherBigDecimal` because they get *normalized* into the same form.

The only difference is a `null` in `otherBigDecimal` would give a `NullPointerException` instead of an assertion error.

Answer (score 8):

The method `assertSame` tests that both are the same object. However, you have two objects which have the same value. To test this, you can use `assertEquals`.

However, you should be aware of some unexpected behavior when using `assertEquals` (which depends on the `equals` method) on `BigDecimal`s. For example, `new BigDecimal("100").divide(new BigDecimal("10.0")).equals(new BigDecimal("10"))` evaluates to `false` because `equals` also looks at the scale of the `BigDecimal` instances.

In many circumstances it is better to compare `BigDecimal`s by using the `compareTo` method:

```
assertTrue(bd1.compareTo(bd2) == 0);
```

Answer (score 3):

Other alternative for specific scale and rounded:

```
import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

...

BigDecimal a = new BigDecimal(100.05);
BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal(100.048);

a = a.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_EVEN);
b = b.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_EVEN);

assertThat(a).isEqualTo(b);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
assertThat(BigDecimal.valueOf(10.00)).isEqualByComparingTo(BigDecimal.valueOf(10));
```

Answer (score 1):

`bd1` and `bd2` are two *different* objects, and since [`assertSame`](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html#assertSame%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object%29) checks the *object reference* using the `==` operator, you're getting that message, see the docs:

> Asserts that two objects **refer to the same object**. If they are not the same, an `AssertionError` without a message is thrown.

You should use `assertEquals` instead, it checks that the two objects are equal - which is what you want.

---

Note that comparing two `BigDecimal` objects using the `==` operator will work as long as their values are cached (for 0 through 10) values.

Answer (score 0):

If you like the assertEquals because it shows you the values in the failure message, and you want to ignore extraneous trailing decimal zeros, you can use the following:

```
BigDecimal bdGood = BigDecimal.valueOf(2.5).setScale(3);
BigDecimal bdBad = BigDecimal.valueOf(2.504);
assertEquals("Passes", BigDecimal.valueOf(2.5), bdGood.stripTrailingZeros());
assertEquals("Fails", BigDecimal.valueOf(2.5), bdBad.stripTrailingZeros());
```

This will reduce the result to the lowest possible scale before the comparison.

Answer (score 0):

I am retriving Bigdecimal from Map and assertion using **assertEquals & assertTrue**. Decimal values are setusing setScale() method.

```
   Map<String, BigDecimal> amtAdjustedMap = new HashMap<>();

    Assertions.assertEquals(amtAdjustedMap.get("amtAdjustedLcy"),new BigDecimal(100000));
    Assertions.assertEquals(amtAdjustedMap.get("amtAdjustedFxRate"),new BigDecimal(7.81676).setScale(5, RoundingMode.HALF_UP));
    Assertions.assertEquals(amtAdjustedMap.get("fxRateAdjustment"),BigDecimal.ONE);

    Assertions.assertTrue(amtAdjustedMap.get("amtAdjustedLcy").compareTo(new BigDecimal(100000))==0);
    Assertions.assertTrue(amtAdjustedMap.get("amtAdjustedFxRate").compareTo(new BigDecimal(7.81676).setScale(5, RoundingMode.HALF_UP))==0);
    Assertions.assertTrue(amtAdjustedMap.get("fxRateAdjustment").compareTo(BigDecimal.ONE)==0);

    BigDecimal bd1= new BigDecimal ("7.2");
    BigDecimal bd2= new BigDecimal ("7.2");
    Assertions.assertTrue(bd1.compareTo(bd2) == 0);
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `AssertEquals` instead of `AssertSame`... reason because `assertequals` checks the value but `assertsame` checks the refrence..